# Getting "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" from Flask API

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, ajax, flask

I have a Flask server and trying to make GET requests to the server via AJAX call. As a result, I am getting the following error in the browser's console:

### GET http://ip:port/endpoint 500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR)

### Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://ip:APIport/endpoint' from origin 'http://ip:websitePort' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Below is the js code I am using to send the request:

```
var xhr;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    var data = x;

    xhr.open("GET", "http://ip:APIport/endpoint");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "image/png");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic somestring);

    xhr.onload = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
            console.log(this.responseText);

            if (callback instanceof Function) {
                callback(results);
            }
        } 
    }

    xhr.onerror = function (e) {
        console.error(xhr.statusText);
    };

    xhr.send(data);
```

Here is my Flask server configuration:

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin
from flask import request


app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)


@app.route('/endpoint', methods=['GET', 'OPTIONS'])
def endpoint():

    result = 'Hello World'

    return result
```

Note that, Flask API is working in a docker container and all works fine when I am doing requests via Postman.

Please help if you have any suggestions concerning to the error?

Comment: Your request requires CORS headers because the port numbers differ. You'll have to configure your server appropriately. The CORS headers will have to be for whatever server responds to "API port" requests.

Comment: What on earth is `xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "image/png");` for? You're making a GET request. You aren't POSTing or PUTting an image file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed GET to POST and all works fine for me, thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add the cross_origin decorator to your function

Try this:

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin 


app = Flask(__name__) 
CORS(app)


@app.route('/endpoint', methods=['GET', 'OPTIONS']) 
@cross_origin()
def endpoint():

    result = 'Hello World'

    return result
```